# Tomcat not closing connections, remains in sleep mode

Tags: tomcat, apache-commons-dbcp

We are using tomcat 6.0.26 with MySql 5.1, the connection to database is set up in server.xml as given below,

```
<GlobalNamingResources>
<!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
     UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
-->
<Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
          type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
          description="User database that can be updated and saved"
          factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
          pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />

 <Resource name="jdbc/abs" type="javax.sql.DataSource"  maxActive="150"   maxIdle="5"  username="XXXXXXXXXXX" testWhileIdle="true"  removeAbandonedTimeout="60"  maxWait="-1" removeAbandoned="true"
    validationQuery="select 1" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" password="XXXXXXXXXXX" minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="30000" timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="300000" url="jdbc:mysql://XXXXXXXXXXXX?autoReconnect=true&amp;useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf-8"/>

    <Resource driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" maxActive="150" maxIdle="5" maxWait="-1" testWhileIdle="true" minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="30000"  removeAbandonedTimeout="60"  timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="300000" name="jdbc/1234" password="XXXXXXXXXXX" removeAbandoned="true" type="javax.sql.DataSource" url="jdbc:mysql:///XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX?autoReconnect=true&amp;useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf-8" username="XXXXXXXXXXX" validationQuery="select 1"/>
```

When I run show full processlist in MySql it shows a lot of connection remaining in sleep mode, what could be causing this?

Regards,

Rohit

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Were you able to resolve the issue ?

Answer (score -1):

A `javax.sql.DataSource` is a connection pool to MySQL. You application server will open some connections to MySQL (which remain in sleep mode) and use them every time you do a:

```
DataSource ds = ...;
// you get one of the 'sleeping' connections here
Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
// you return the connection to the pool here (it does not actually closes it)
conn.close();
```